# Mismatch error on an array w/application.worksheetfunction

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I am trying to take a complex excel formula and convert into a `application.worksheetfunction` VBA process so it's evaluated during code execution.

I've asked this issue previously and am still having a hard time concluding where/what I need to amend in order to get this to execute appropriately

Basically I am taking the below excel formula and working to convert it into VBA code with dynamic cell ranges (Also `$AM41` is dynamic and would change in accordance with the code definitions)

```
=SUMIFS($N:$N,$B:$B,INDEX($B:$B,MAX(INDEX(($C:$C=$AM41)*ROW($C:$C),0))),$C:$C,$AM41)
```

My code so far is as such

```
    Dim mws As Worksheet
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim mwsN As Range
    Dim mwsC As Range
    Dim mwsB As Range
    Dim mwsLast As Range

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set mws = Sheets("Marks")
    Set mwsN = mws.Range("N:N")
    Set mwsC = mws.Range("C:C")
    Set mwsB = mws.Range("B:B")
    LastMWSR = mws.Cells(mws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ClastMWSC = mws.Cells(1, mws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set mwsLast = mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC - 1)


    'error, is thrown just below this line

    mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC).Value = _
    wf.SumIfs(mwsN, mwsB, wf.Index(mwsB, wf.Max(wf.Index((mwsC = mwsLast) * wf.Row(mwsC), 0))), mwsC, mwsLast)
```

I believe the mismatch error is being thrown right here

```
wf.Max(wf.Index((mwsC = mwsLast)
```

I don't know how to communicate that array into VBA terms.

Can anyone help illustrating how to make this dynamic and clear the mismatch error?

Comment: You'd need to rethink the entire approach. There is no `Worksheetfunction.Row`, and you can't compare a multi-cell range (or array) to a value using `=`. You could either use `Evaluate` and pass the formula string, or just put formulas into the cells and then convert to values.

Comment: Can you use Evaluate with a dynamic range though? I'm fine throwing in a formula then pasting it as values, but I need that $AM41 to be dynamic. Can evaluate do that?

Comment: It's just a string so you can adjust the row number as needed by concatenation

Comment: @Rory - If I can use `=ROW(1:1)` OR `=MATCH("abc", ROW(1:1), 0)` on the worksheet, then why isn't there a `Worksheetfunction.Row` ?

Comment: Hi, simply just use VBA row, there is no ROW function by WF. do: `range("**").row` and this will do the same, no need to `wf.row(**)`

Comment: @Jeeped You don't need one for a single row number (since a `Range` has a `Row` property) and it's a little esoteric to need an *array* of row numbers.

Comment: @Rory - I agree. However, an array of row numbers may be necessary for an array formula on the worksheet and that is what the op is attempting to recreate with Index in its *array form*. I think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and the real issue is to find a  native vba method that returns the same results. Besides, full column references in an array formula ...? Surely there is a better way.

Comment: @Jeeped If you're simply trying to recreate a formula as VBA, you may as well just use `Evaluate`. I'd be very surprised if using umpteen `Worksheetfunction` type calls was more efficient. Frankly, there are also usually better ways than using `ROW()` in an array formula anyway.- e.g. here replacing `INDEX($B:$B,MAX(INDEX(($C:$C=$AM41)*ROW($C:$C),0)))` with a `LOOKUP` formula - preferably avoiding entire columns!

Comment: @jeeped Also, in my defence, I didn't write Excel's OM, so can't tell you **why** anything is the way it is. :)